# Array of strings causes segmentation fault when first element is not initialized

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have this code block which has an array of 10 strings. Two things stand out to me in this:

- The first being that when doing `char *words[10] = { "anything "};` I was under the impression that every element of the words array would be set to `"anything"` but it appears that the only the first is and every other element is `NULL`.  My thought process was that it would be similar to doing `int x[10] = { 0 };` but perhaps that is not the case with a 2-dimensional array.
- The second odd thing is that whenever I do not initialize the first word in the array, the program causes a segmentation fault, but when I do initialize it it works as expected.

My questions are:

1. why does only the first element be set to `"anything"` and not all of them and
2. why does not initializing the first word cause it to segfault?

Compiled and ran on Ubuntu 18.04

gcc -Wall test.c -o test

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // char *words[10]; // Causes seg fault
    char *words[10] = { "anything" }; // Does not cause seg fault

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        printf("Word %d: %s\n", i, words[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output when seg fault occurs

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Output when no seg fault

```
Word 0: anything
Word 1: (null)
Word 2: (null)
Word 3: (null)
Word 4: (null)
Word 5: (null)
Word 6: (null)
Word 7: (null)
Word 8: (null)
Word 9: (null)
```

Output I expected to see

```
Word 0: anything
Word 1: anything
Word 2: anything
Word 3: anything
Word 4: anything
Word 5: anything
Word 6: anything
Word 7: anything
Word 8: anything
Word 9: anything
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your initial assumptions.  Here is a summary of the missing concepts:

- when an object (structure or array) is defined with an initializer, the elements that do not have an initializer are set to the *zero* of their type: `0` for integral types, `0.0` for `double`, a null pointer for pointer types.
- `char *words[10] = { "anything" };` does not define a 2D array, but an array of 10 pointers to `char`.  The initializer defines the first element to point to a string literal `"anything"`, the remaining 9 elements are intialized to the *zero* of the type `char *`: a null pointer. The definition is thus equivalent to

  ```
    char *words[10] = { "anything", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  ```

  or, assuming `NULL` is defined from a standard header:

  ```
    char *words[10] = {
        "anything", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
    };
  ```
- `printf("Word %d: %s\n", i, words[i]);` has **undefined behavior** if `words[i]` is an invalid pointer, including the null pointer. Your C library makes a special case of the null pointer for the `%s` conversion and prints `(null)` but this behavior is not guaranteed by the C Standard and other C libraries may behave differently, possibly causing a segmentation fault.

  Note also that even with a lenient C library, the behavior is still undefined as the C compiler may convert calls to `printf` to alternatives that are equivalent according to the C Standard but lack special handling of the null pointer: for example `printf("%s\n", words[i]);` can be converted to a call to `puts(words[i])` which might cause a segmentation fault for a null pointer argument.
- An array defined without an initializer at the local scope in a function body is **uninitialized**, ie: its elements have indeterminate values.  Dereferencing such uninitialized pointers has undefined behavior, possibly a segmentation fault.
- An array defined without an initializer at the global scope or with a `static` keyword at a local scope has all its elements initialized to the *zero* of the array type.

Here is a modified version with fully defined behavior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *word2[10];

int main(void)
{
    static char *word1[10];
    char *word[10] = { "anything" };

    printf("char *word[10] = { \"anything\" };\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("word[%d]: %s\n", i, word[i] ? word[i] : "(null)");
    }
    printf("\nstatic char *word1[10];\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("word1[%d]: %s\n", i, word1[i] ? word1[i] : "(null)");
    }
    printf("\n/* global */ char *word2[10];\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("word2[%d]: %s\n", i, word2[i] ? word2[i] : "(null)");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
char *word[10] = { "anything" };
word[0]: anything
word[1]: (null)
word[2]: (null)
word[3]: (null)
word[4]: (null)
word[5]: (null)
word[6]: (null)
word[7]: (null)
word[8]: (null)
word[9]: (null)

static char *word1[10];
word1[0]: (null)
word1[1]: (null)
word1[2]: (null)
word1[3]: (null)
word1[4]: (null)
word1[5]: (null)
word1[6]: (null)
word1[7]: (null)
word1[8]: (null)
word1[9]: (null)

/* global */ char *word2[10];
word2[0]: (null)
word2[1]: (null)
word2[2]: (null)
word2[3]: (null)
word2[4]: (null)
word2[5]: (null)
word2[6]: (null)
word2[7]: (null)
word2[8]: (null)
word2[9]: (null)
```